# How to upgrade nodejs to latest version

Tags: node.js, upgrade

I'd like to upgrade from the LTS to 8.x.  I need to integrate this into an existing project. What's the best way to do that so that my project continues to work no problems after the upgrade?
(I'm on windows).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using windows it is easy to upgrade to the latest node js version.

Just reinstall node from the .msi in Windows from the node website.

That will do the trick.

Your project will not be affected after the upgradations.

Also, npm will be upgraded as well.

It's safe to do the following after the upgradations.

```
npm cache clean
npm update -g
```

### EDIT

I just want to add the use of nvm that manages multiple node versions without any conflicts to each other versions.
You could look into it [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?  I've read a couple of big threads here on the subject and they say that (upgrading via the .msi) doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried this once. It worked more me back then. Comparing to linux and mac updation, for windows upgradation installing via msi is the best option. Remember to clean the cache, after your installation.

Comment: Ok, cheers.  I'll wait a while and see if anyone else has any warnings to offer, and then I might give it a go.

Comment: sure thing. it was sometimes ago. i am using linux now.

Comment: I went ahead and did it, and as far as I can tell it's all working fine.  Cheers for that.